# Using NuGet makes project incompatible with .NET FW 4 and lower

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

Project is written in VB .NET in Visual Studio 2013 and targets .NET Framework 4.

I've used NuGet to download two .dlls: AngleSharp and NHunspell. NuGet adds its own reference to System.Runtime and System.Threading.Tasks. The path is

D:\Development\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.8\lib\net40\System.Runtime.dll

Although the project targets .NET Framework 4, the dlls in question show runtime "v4.0.30319" in the details pane, and a regex search has revealed no reference to a Framework higher than 4.0 in my entire solution, I still cannot reference my dll from a project that targets 4.0.

If I compile my .dll and then reference it from another project that targets Framework 4 I get the following warning:

The primary reference "MyOtherProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=2.6.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "MyOtherProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=2.6.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

I get the same warning for System.Runtime.

If I target 4.5 or higher from MyOtherProject it compiles perfectly. I need it to be 4.0 though because it needs to work with a legacy system.

Comment: Did you add the nuget to the other projects you reference this project from?  this is needed so the dlls are added to these projects as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using NuGet makes project incompatible with .NET FW 4 and lower

You should also add the NuGet package `AngleSharp` and `NHunspell` to the project which reference the project "`MyOtherProject`".

According to the [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp/), you can notice that that package have a Dependencies for .NETFramework 4.0 but no dependencies for .NETFramework 4.5:

[image]

After installed those two packages to the project, the references `System.Runtime` and `System.Threading.Tasks` will added to the project, but when we add this project as reference to other project, those two references will not add. That why you get the error "*could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Threading.Tasks"*".

To resolve this issue, you should add the NuGet packages to the project which reference the project "`MyOtherProject`".